# Importrange to change cells in multiple spreadsheets at once with a script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I want all spreadsheets to update with data i put into a main spreadsheet. I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 8, file "Code")
> here is line 8: var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');

I want to put data in WORK sheet and have NUMBER sheet update on different spreadsheets.

```
function getdata() { 
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1CXEKiJBHNKk_-aI3lcEcSUSXq98uotVk").getFiles()  
while (files.hasNext()) { 
  var file = files.next();
  var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());  
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('WORK');  
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A'); 
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues(); 
  var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('NUMBER'); 
  var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:A'); 
  destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
```

}
}

Comment: function getdata() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1CXEKiJBHNKk_-aI3lcEcSUSXq98uotVk").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      
      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('WORK');
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
      
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('NUMBER'); 
      var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:A'); 
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);

Comment: I added  the code that you pasted as a comment but it's incomplete. Pleas add the missing parts.

Comment: Please add more details. Which one is the line 8? Is your script a bounded script or a stand-alone script?

Comment: . Stand alone. here is line 8: var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the importan details about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the error occurs because there isn't a sheet named `WORK` or `NUMBER`. Please bear in mind that the Google Apps Script methods are case sensitive.

Comment: I have sheets named WORK and NUMBER. All caps.